# In elasticsearch a record can be searched but cannot be fetch by ID

Tags: elasticsearch

Just now a strange thing happened. I used ran a search request on an elasticsearch cluster.

```
curl http://<cluster>/<index>/_search  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "query": { "match": { "<field>": "<value>" } } } '
```

The response was

```
{ "hits": { "hits": [{ "_id": "<the ID>", ... }], ... }, ... }
```

Then I tried to query this doc.

```
curl http://<cluster>/<index>/_doc/<the ID>
```

But it responded

```
{"_index":"<index>","_type":"_doc","_id":"<the ID>","found":false}
```

I tried to delete this record, but it was also not found.

```
{"_index":"<index>","_type":"_doc","_id":"<the ID>","_version":1,"result":"not_found","_shards":{ ... }, ... }
```

I finally used [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/docs-delete-by-query.html).

What could possibily cause this issue?

Elasticsearch version: 7.10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually means that the record was [indexed with a routing value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/docs-get.html#get-routing), which means you need to provide that routing value to retrieve it, update it and/or delete it.

You can try different routing values, up to the number of primary shards that you have, i.e. if you have 5 primary shards, one of the following must return your document

```
curl http://<cluster>/<index>/_doc/<the ID>?routing=0
curl http://<cluster>/<index>/_doc/<the ID>?routing=1
curl http://<cluster>/<index>/_doc/<the ID>?routing=2
curl http://<cluster>/<index>/_doc/<the ID>?routing=3
curl http://<cluster>/<index>/_doc/<the ID>?routing=4
```

You can find the routing value used for your document in the search response in the `_routing` field value.

```
{ "hits": { "hits": [{ "_id": "<the ID>", "_routing": "<the ROUTING>", ... }], ... }, ... }
```